# Print id in genealogytree

Tags: tikz-pgf, genealogytree

Is there something like a command `\gtrDBid` working like `\gtrDBsex` in the package `genealogytree`?

My setting to understand the usage of this command:

- The file

  ```
  family/family.tex
  ```

  holds the tex-code for the genealogytree.
- In directory

  ```
  db/
  ```

  are all pictures saved with the id for the person in filename. Pattern is

  ```
  P-<id>.jpg
  ```

  For example: `db/P-ForenameSurename1990.jpg`

My example code works so far:

```
\documentclass[]{standalone}

\usepackage[all]{genealogytree}
\gtrloadlanguage{german}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc} 
\usepackage{hyperref}


\begin{document}


    \gtrset{image prefix=../db/P-}
    \gtrset{language=german}

    \gtrset{gauss/.style={
            processing=database,
            node size=2.4cm,
            level size=3.5cm,
            box={
                fit basedim=7pt,boxsep=2pt,segmentation style=solid, halign=flush left,before upper=\parskip1pt, \gtrDBsex,drop fuzzy shadow, 
                if image defined={
                    %add to width=25mm,right=25mm,
                    width=49mm,right=25mm, 
                    underlay={
                        \begin{tcbclipinterior}\path[fill overzoom image=\gtrDBimage]
                            ([xshift=-24mm]interior.south east) rectangle (interior.north east);
                        \end{tcbclipinterior}},
                    }{},
                },
            }
        }


    \begin{tikzpicture}[scale=0.94,transform shape]

    \genealogytree[
        gauss, 
    ]{
        child{
            g[id=SurnameForename1990]{
                male,
                name={\pref{Forename} \surn{Surename}},
                birth={1990-01-01}{Home},
                comment={\LaTeX-enthusiast, \gtrDBsex},
                image=SurnameForename1990.jpg,
            }
        }
    }

    \end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

What I now want to do, is to change the line

```
image=SurnameForename1990.jpg,
```

into something like

```
image=\gtrDBid.jpg,
```

Are there any possibilites? Thank you!

Comment: Welcome to TeX.se and thanks for posting an example document. Doesn't the `\gtrDBimage` macro described in §2.3.4 of the manual do what you want?  (No idea, I've never used the package).

Answer (score 1):

The `id` can be displayed by `\gtrnodeid`, but this macro is too cunning to be used like you want to. The more basic `\gtr@gkv@id` can be used instead.

The following solution will only work

- if every person has an associated `id`
- if every person has an image following your pattern.

If your applications fulfills these prerequisites, try the following:

```
\documentclass[]{standalone}

\usepackage[all]{genealogytree}
\gtrloadlanguage{german}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{hyperref}


\begin{document}

    \makeatletter
    %\gtrset{image prefix=../db/P-}
    \gtrset{language=german}

    \gtrset{gauss/.style={
            processing=database,
            node size=2.4cm,
            level size=3.5cm,
            box={
                fit basedim=7pt,boxsep=2pt,segmentation style=solid, halign=flush left,before upper=\parskip1pt, \gtrDBsex,drop fuzzy shadow,
                %if image defined={
                    %add to width=25mm,right=25mm,
                    width=49mm,right=25mm,
                    underlay={
                        \begin{tcbclipinterior}\path[fill overzoom image=../db/P-\gtr@gkv@id]
                            ([xshift=-24mm]interior.south east) rectangle (interior.north east);
                        \end{tcbclipinterior}},
                %    }{},
                },
            }
        }
    \makeatother

    \begin{tikzpicture}[scale=0.94,transform shape]

    \genealogytree[
        gauss,
    ]{
        child{
            g[id=SurnameForename1990]{
                male,
                name={\pref{Forename} \surn{Surename}},
                birth={1990-01-01}{Home},
                comment={\LaTeX-enthusiast, \gtrDBsex},
                %image=SurnameForename1990.jpg,
            }
        }
    }

    \end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```